# Use cacheAddMethod for methods of datasource AX2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

There is a form have two display methods. So form load is so slowly. I searched and found this way;

```
public void init()
{
    super();
    MyTable_DS.cacheAddMethod(tableMethodStr(MyTable, dispCreditBalance));
}
```

but my display methods not in table methods node. My methods under form -> datasources -> table -> method node. So tableMethodStr can't see my methods.

How can use this cacheAddMethod in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching of form display methods is not supported. You may try to enable the "CacheDateMethod" attribute of the form field, but I expect it will not work.

If possible (not dependant on form variables) move the display method to the table and remove from the form.

A workaround will be to use a map to store the result and only recompute when needed not found in map. You can see an example in the Pastebin in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11950522/4509).

Comment: @Mumble you can use `SysClientCacheDataMethodAttribute` as well. See `\Data Dictionary\Tables\CustInvoiceTable\Methods\displayCorrectionState` for example.

Comment: Sure, on table display methods, not form display methods.

Comment: Yes, I was agreeing with your suggestion to move it to the table and use the attribute.